# Open file with default application from command line

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line

On Windows XP, how does one open a file with its default application from the command line?

As far as I know, this should work from a command prompt or batch file:

```
start "path to my file"
```

Unfortunately in my case, this only opens a new command prompt window for most file types. (It does work for .exe file though...)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try this.

```
START "" "path to my file"
```

The `START` command treats the first set of `""` as the text to use for the title of the window, so just include an empty pair.

Comment: How can I make this work for opening PowerShell via a command in batch file? Right now, nothing happens when it hits the line `powershell` or `powershell.exe`. when I make it `start powershell` or `start powershell.exe` nothing happens.

Comment: Does this work on all versions of Windows or is there a minimum version?

Comment: It works on all versions I believe...as far back as Windows 95 any way. I'm not sure about versions before that.

Answer (score 10):

```
explorer "filename"
```

works for xp and other windows (95 or higher)
If it does not work, you haven't associated that extention type with a program.

Comment: This also works well if you use Bash on Windows: `explorer.exe "filename"`

Comment: This is what I came looking to do. It works nicely with some alias too, e.g. `alias open="explorer.exe"` lets you just call `open file.txt`.

Answer (score 9):

Don't use `START`. Just type the name of the file.
`readme.txt` opens `readme.txt` in Notepad (or in whatever default `.txt` handler you have in place).

Note that if there are spaces in the name, you must handle them. A good way is to use double quotes.
`"read me.txt"`

Comment: Under windows 7, you need the START command.

Comment: @Gerrit No, you don't. If the program in question is in your path and your default handlers are set up properly, all you have to do it provide the path and file name and it will open.

Comment: Start is nice because it will exit the batch script after launching your file/app, rather than leaving a cmd window open until you close the file/app

Answer (score 4):

Using PowerShell

```
Start-Process "<fullname>"
```