# How can I open a file with its default application from the MinGW Bash prompt?

Tags: bash, file-association, mingw

In the default windows command prompt you can open a file from the command prompt by entering the name. See *[Open file with default application from command line](https://superuser.com/questions/550138/open-file-with-default-application-from-command-line)*.

Is there an equivalent in the MinGW Bash prompt?

Comment: See this [link](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/mingw_for_first_time_users_howto) for first time usage.

Comment: I don't understand.. Using the method from the link you provided, start works exactly the same for me using the MinGW bash prompt.  "start ." opens the windows explorer in the current directory.  "start ./file.7z" fires up 7zip with the file..

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this counts, but i noticed on windows 10 that, if you list the files in the MinGW terminal and double click to highlight the file of interest, you can then right-click and the 1st option is to open it (with the default application)...

It's not exactly typing it and hitting enter to open, but you do NOT need a windows-explorer open in that folder either (this seems very close to what is asked).